# Closing Bootstrap Modal When Condition Met

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal v3.2.0, which shows on page load. It is being used as an age verification pop up.

I am looking for a way to close this modal if a condition has been met. Basically, when the user clicks a button, I want it to close but I also want to ensure that the modal does not appear again on page load after clicking that button.

Here is the code

```js
 $(window).load(function(){        
   $('#myModal').modal('show')
    });
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="footer-close" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code works to successfully load the bootstrap modal on page load and closes the modal when you click on the close button however the modal will still appear again on page load. As I am not very strong with Javascript, I am not certain how to go about a conditional or if statement. So far I have the bare bones:

```js
if (condition) {
  $("#myModal").modal('hide');
} else { 
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Inside the original if statement should be if the close button has been clicked. It should also prevent the modal from auto loading again. Maybe I don't even need the else statement.

Their might even be a better option I haven't considered. Any help much appreciated.

```js
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
    
    $('#over18').on('click', function (e) {

    $('#myModal').modal('hide')

});
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="https://google.co.uk" class="close" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></a>
        <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0078/4449/5437/files/Flavour_Vapour_Icon_300x300.png?v=1550053751" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="modal-p">You must be at least 18 years old to enter this site.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="over18" class="btn btn-default">I am 18 or older</button>
        <a href="https://google.co.uk" id="under18" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">I am under 18</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For additional clarity, if I use the following code, when you click the button it does show the alert, so the javascript and code is working for that, it simply won't work when using the bootstrap: $('#myModal').modal('hide');

```js
$('#over18').on('click', function () {

    alert('Hello!');

});
```

So after some more playing around, the following code will auto open the modal, when the over 18 button is clicked it will be closed, and an alert will appear to say the modal is about to be hidden. I done this to make sure the javascript was working.

The line that is calling the alert is where I should be putting the localstorage line to ensure the modal does not show again. However this does not work.

```js
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
    
  $("#over18").click(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("hide");
  });
  
  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    alert('The modal is about to be hidden.');
  });
```

Comment: use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to store your condition

Comment: Thanks urbz. I plan to store the condition locally, once I know what condition to use. lol.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, to decide whether to show the modal:

```
// On initial page load
if (localStorage.getItem('age-verified') !== true) {
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
}
```

Then, if the modal shows - do something like this:

```
// Upon the age being confirmed
$('#footer-close').on('click', function() { // This is for illustration - handle the close event on the modal however you choose
    $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    localStorage.setItem('age-verified', true);
});
```

**Updated - based on new code you posted**

I've managed to create a working example for you. The script tags in your HTML document need to be in the same order as below. Bootstrap relies on jQuery - so that needs to be declared first.

Also to note - if you try running this example in StackOverflow's code snipped editor, it won't work - as code snippets are sandboxed, and don't have access to localStorage. You should be able to run it locally on your own computer though.

```js
if (localStorage.getItem('age-verified') !== true) {
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
  
  $('#over18').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    
    localStorage.setItem('age-verified', true);
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Your page content here</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <a href="https://google.co.uk" class="close" role="button"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></a>
            <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0078/4449/5437/files/Flavour_Vapour_Icon_300x300.png?v=1550053751" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p class="modal-p">You must be at least 18 years old to enter this site.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="over18" class="btn btn-default">I am 18 or older</button>
            <a href="https://google.co.uk" id="under18" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">I am under 18</a>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alex that looks promising. As I don't fully understand Javascript just yet I am assuming the html modal needs adjusted in some way for this to work? What does the 'age-verified' refer to?

Comment: Yes - the logic in your form values will need to be dealt with by you. 'age-verified' is just the name for a thing we've set in local storage. You can call it whatever you want, and assign almost any value to it. Check out this simple example https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: That's actually very clever. Thanks Alex. Will look into implementing this and update if I have success.

Comment: Been at this for the past few hours, I cannot get it to behave. the age-verified statement, should that be set as an id to an HTML element?

Comment: No. For clarity - update your question with the code you currently have (update any explanations as necessary too - it helps others who come across this problem). I'll take another look :)

Comment: Ok, I tried using the suggested method above, which will auto load the modal, however when clicking the over 18 button, I cannot get the modal to dismiss using javascript. I can dismiss it using the bootstrap: data-dismiss="modal".

I have assigned the over 18 button the ID of over18 and trying to simply use javascript at this point to dismiss the modal, once I get this working I can then get looking at the LocalStorage element.

$('#over18').on('click', function (e) {

    $('#myModal').modal('hide')

});

Comment: Understood - update your question with the code you have as of now and I'll take another look :)

Comment: I also tried this code:

document.getElementById('over18').addEventListener('click', function () {
 $("#myModal").modal('hide');
 localStorage.setItem('over18', true);
}

Comment: Comments aren't a great place to put code. To help you, I need to see your modal html and javascript exactly as you have it now.

Comment: i've added what I have now. So as it stands, it will auto show the modal with javascript. It won't close it however.

Comment: @Andrew - I've updated my answer. Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: will have a play around, doesn't want to work for me, possibly as I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0?

Comment: Ahhh! Yes that would be why. I'll update my answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official bootstrap reference guide to do this depending on what version of bootstrap you are using. See [Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#show)